# Dropdown Menu and Hover Menu (Sub Menu)

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, hover, submenu

Istanbul section right pulldown a hover menu how do I do it?

[image]

```
<li class="dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Otoparklar <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a aria-controls="overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#istanbul">İstanbul</a></li>
        <li><a aria-controls="overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#eskisehir">Eskişehir</a></li>
        <li><a aria-controls="overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#aydin">Aydın</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I found this link and I hope it helps you: (http://www.htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns/). If not, let me know in order to try explain you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this dropdown menu with CSS

This is a easy example how to do.
First, add class to know which level is it.

```
<ul class="firstLevel">
```

Second, add css for hover of this element, do something to his son

```
ul.firstLevel li:hover > ul
```

Then, add colors, transitions, ...

```css
ul.secondLevel {
  display: none;
}
ul.firstLevel li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul class="firstLevel">
  <li>
    <a href="">Birds</a>
    <ul class="secondLevel">
      <li>
        <a href="">Ratites</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Fowl</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Neoaves</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you need is:

HTML:

```
<nav id="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Dropdown</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="">example</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        font: 300 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        background: #333;
        margin: 15px;
    }

    article {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #666;
    }

    section {
        clear: left;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 45px;
        font-weight: 100;
        letter-spacing: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1, #main_content, #dog_link {
        padding: 15px;
    }

    p {
        margin: 15px 0;
    }

    a {
        color: #06c;
    }

    #main_nav ul {
        background: white;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transition: .5s;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    #main_nav li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 150px;
        list-style: none;
        -webkit-transition: .5s;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    #main_nav > ul > li > a, h1 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #main_nav a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        color: #000;
    }

    #main_nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #main_nav ul ul ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }

    #main_nav li:hover, #main_nav li:hover li {
        background: #ddd;
    }

    #main_nav li li:hover, #main_nav li li:hover li {
        background: #bbb;
    }

    #main_nav li li li:hover {
        background: #999;
    }

    #main_nav li:hover > ul {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szs4Lapn/1/

In my opinion, the link I gave you on the comment explains it very well. In fact I came up with this solution, after reading that post. Please leave a comment to let me know if I was helpful. :)

Links:

- http://www.htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns/
- http://www.htmldog.com/examples/dropdowns3/

Comment: I've got another problem First it is seen running smoothly. Going to the page I want. Clicking a second time, but do not go.
video:https://yadi.sk/i/etw6xCF6xgKZG

Comment: The problem is that you use the # sumbol. This doesn't reload the page. In the first time how do you reload it? Using Javascript?

Comment: Using Javascript you can achieve this using this code: `<a onclick="window.location.href += 'example1';
location.reload();">example1</a>`. Since you already have the # symbol, this code will add the 'example1' after the # symbol and then reload the page.

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle or provide the code you use, in order to help you furthermore.

Comment: <a href="#sishane" onClick="window.location.reload( true );">Şişhane</a> 

thank you so much. it was