# Dropdown menu content and last-child

Tags: html, css

```
CODE:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qyVMj/140/

Current dropdown image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH22K.jpg

The secondary dropdown content appears on top of the previous. The "Man" link doesn't even appear.

And I also would like to put the "Contact" on the right side of the ul.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle, it's so much easier to fix code that runs.

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful to know what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to just make both subnavs show, or are you trying to make a secondary subnavigation appear when you click men/women?

Comment: Im trying to make both subnavs show when I hover. @DanLeveille

Comment: jsFiddle in there now @frenchie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is this code:

HTML:

```
<nav id="main_nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="">Women</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Hats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Shirts</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">Men</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Hats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Jeans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Shirts</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" style="float:right">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: gray;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #333;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

ul:last-child li
{
    border: none;
    float: right !important;
}
```

As for the colors and the design you can make the appropriate changes in css.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szs4Lapn/4/

Links

- http://www.htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns
- [Dropdown Menu and Hover Menu (Sub Menu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261133/dropdown-menu-and-hover-menu-sub-menu/40265851#40265851)

Answer (score 0):

Your .dropdown-content div (which is absolute positioned) contains two .dropdown-content divs, which are also absolute positioning themselves, which is why they're overlapping on top of each other (and why they have dropshadows).

Removing those classes on the sub-sub navs fixes it:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Women</a>
        <div>
            <a href="#">Hats</a>
            <a href="#">Jeans</a>
            <a href="#">Shirts</a>
        </div>
    <a href="#">Man</a>
        <div>
            <a href="#">Hats</a>
            <a href="#">Jeans</a>
            <a href="#">Shirts</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qyVMj/141/

Also, it's typically better to structure navigations using nested lists (`<ul>` and `<li>`) for proper semantics and accessibility.

Comment: It stays almost the same to me. I want to be only "Women"+"Men" when I hover on "Products". And when I hover "Women" or "Men" the "Hats", "Jeans" and "Shirt" appear. @DanLeveille

Comment: @fabimetabi Ah, I see, that's different than what I interpreted from your comment.

Comment: Sorry. I also interpreted your comment badly, sadly. @DanLeveille